# Moving pointer in array

Tags: c++

This program crashes and I can't find any nonlegal action regarding getting array content and moving  pointer. What is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {


    int * p =  new int [20];
    for(int i=0 ; i<20 ;i++ )
        {
            p[i]=i;
        }

    for(int i=0 ; i<20 ;i++ )
        {
            printf("%d ",*p );
            p++;
        }


    delete [] p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question: Why are you using `new` in the first place? You're going through a lot of extra gyration to get pretty much the result you'd get from just making `p` an array/`std::vector`/`std::array` local to `main`. You've gotten lots of advice about how to keep the `new`/`delete` from crashing, but none that points out that you shouldn't be using them to start with (and even when you need `new`-like capabilities, you should look at `make_shared` and `make_unique` instead of using `new` directly).

Comment: @JerryCoffin let me answer that - mostly because majority of C++ books, resources, courses (even the University ones) still prefer to show how to implement linked list in C and then to compile it with C++ compiler. People are still teaching other people how to feel comfortable inside "C ghetto" (as Bartosz Milewski named it).

Answer (score 6):

You're changing your `p` pointer, and then you're trying to delete memory after the original allocated memory:

```
delete [] p;
```

Save the the original pointer to some temporary iterator pointer and increment it, and not the original one:

```
    int *t = p;
    for(int i=0 ; i<20 ;i++ )
    {
        printf("%d ",*t );
        t++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are deleting a pointer pointing to the next element after your memory block.

Answer (score 2):

Save starting pointer of array in another pointer and delete that old pointer on the end.